# PostgreSQL database doesn't connect

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, tomcat

I'm creating a dynamic web project with eclipse and I want to use tomcat 7.0.50 and a postgresql database using a connection pool.
I already copied the postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar file in apache-tomcat-7.0.50/lib.
That's the context.xml file inside apache-tomcat-7.0.50/conf:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
 <Resource 
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           name="jdbc/Fantacalcio" 
           factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
           driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
           url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Fantacalcio" 
           username="postgres"
           password="mypassword"
           initialSize="0"
           maxActive="80" 
           maxIdle = "30" 
           minIdle="20"
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
           testOnBorrow="true"
           validationQuery="SELECT 1" 
           validationInterval="30000" 
           removeAbandoned="true"
           removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
           logAbandoned="true" 
           abandonWhenPercentageFull="60"
       jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer"/>
</Context>
```

this is the web.xml file inside the WEB-INF folder of the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Fantacalcio</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
     <description></description>
     <display-name>AbstractDatabaseServlet</display-name>
     <servlet-name>AbstractDatabaseServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>servlet.AbstractDatabaseServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AbstractDatabaseServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AbstractDatabaseServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ShowIndexServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ShowIndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.ShowIndexServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ShowIndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ShowIndexServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>Connection Pool</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/Fantacalcio</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.Datasource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

This is the java class responsible for the connection pool:

```
public abstract class AbstractDatabaseServlet extends HttpServlet {

  protected static final DataSource DS;

  static {

    InitialContext cxt;
    DataSource ds = null;
    try {
        cxt = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/Fantacalcio");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        ds = null;
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {DS = ds;}

  }
}
```

And this is the servlet that wants to get a connection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ShowIndexServlet extends AbstractDatabaseServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

    Connection con = null;

    try {
        con = DS.getConnection();
        // use of connection con to interact with the database...

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Edit: the complete stacktrace after leaving the namingException

```
15-feb-2014 18.53.27 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
15-feb-2014 18.53.27 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Fantacalcio' did not find a matching property.
15-feb-2014 18.53.27 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
15-feb-2014 18.53.27 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
15-feb-2014 18.53.27 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 610 ms
15-feb-2014 18.53.27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
15-feb-2014 18.53.27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
15-feb-2014 18.53.28 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci onStartup
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocketJARs to the  tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in  $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API  will be available. 
15-feb-2014 18.53.28 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
15-feb-2014 18.53.28 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
15-feb-2014 18.53.28 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1225 msjavax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource  instance
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:146)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at servlet.AbstractDatabaseServlet.<clinit>(AbstractDatabaseServlet.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
15-feb-2014 18.54.05 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ShowIndexServlet] in context with path [/Fantacalcio] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at servlet.ShowIndexServlet.doGet(ShowIndexServlet.java:38)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

P.S. I'm italian, sorry for my imperfect english!

Comment: Please post the exact exception (including the stacktrace)

Comment: Can you connect to the database server's IP address using psql utility?

Comment: You should not use a static initializer for this, at the time your classes get loaded the datasource might not yet exist. Use the managed init methods of GenericServlet for that...

Comment: I add the exact exception including the stacktrace. Yes, I can connect to the database, also directly executing the sql files from eclipse. My problem is use the connection for the servlets.
Can you help me with the code I should use? I'm not able to get a property connection

Comment: You are hiding the actual exception by re-throwing an `IllegalStateException`. Set the original `NamingException` as the cause of the `IllegalStateException` so that the stack-trace shows where the `NamingException` originated from.

Comment: In my PostgreSQL days, I had to open it up to the public. Maybe [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) will help.

Comment: I did the change that vanOekel suggested me. Now you can see the NamingException thrown

Comment: Has this resolved the issue?